# ¿Cómo surge la expresión "bailar en una pata"?

Tags: expresiones, hispanoamérica

Según el DLE, *bailar en una pata* es

> loc. verb. coloq. Can. y Am. Estar muy contento.

La expresión suena a una metáfora entendible (te pones a saltar con una sola pierna de la felicidad), y al revisar en Google Ngrams aparece escrita en 1890 y se consolida en el siglo anterior, pero no vi referencias en el Corpus de la RAE o en otros documentos. ¿Si es cierta la hipótesis de los *saltos por felicidad*? ¿Dónde y cuándo surge la misma?